# how to find me and my followers posts in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have user, post and follows relations like below

user1-[:FOLLOWS]-user2-[:POSTED]-post

How can I get all posts which are made by my followers and myself in a cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can uniquely identify yourself by an ID:

```
MATCH (me:User {Id: 1})<-[:FOLLOWS*0..1]-(follower)-[:POSTED]->(post)
RETURN post;
```

Rationale: in the case where the length of the `:FOLLOWS` relationship is 0, `me == follower`, so the query returns your posts as well.

You can find an example here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dexd4p